# Is ag-grid-react grouping feature need ag-grid enterprise edition?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I used ag-grid-react for my reactJS website. I need to use ag-grid's row-grouping feature but I couldn't find a working demo of it without importing "**ag-grid-enterprise**"

I already tried there demo's in the site but all of the using "**ag-grid-enterprise**" library with '**ag-grid-community**' library. Without enterprice edition it won't render collapsable items in group column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The ag-grid grouping feature won't work without the **ag-grid-enterprise** library.

Answer (score 1):

Read its documentation : [ag-Grid doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php) 
On the left pane, expand the topic named Features, scroll down/up to see if there is any features that have label of enterprise attached on it. Features that are only available in enterprise edition include :

- Row Grouping
- Tree Data
- Pivot
- Master-Detail
- Excel Export